# How to build image with webpack for React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I want to use image in React using webpack. I tried to use `url-loader` and `file-loader` but both failed.

Currently, my webpack.config.js is below - removed other loader settings:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: `${__dirname}/src/App.js`,
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      ...
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/, loader: 'file?name=images/[name].[ext]' },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

The problem is that no files are generated under dist directory. And ofcourse, next code fails: `<img src="./dist/images/machi.png" />`.

file-loader version is 0.8.5.

`"file-loader": "^0.8.5"`

Please tell me how to use image in webpack react.

Comment: Do you get any compilation errors? Have you tried adding `./` to the beginning of your `name=images` loader specification?

Comment: how are you requiring the image in your component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there are several different ways to require the image in webpack.

**1. Use the [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) and [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader), then load the images asynchronously**

The file-loader didn't parse your html markup, it just allow you to require specific type of file, and that kind of file will be serve as a **__WEBPACK_MODULE__**.

So assuming you have html file A,

```
<!-- htmlA -->
<img src='./image/whatever.png' />
```

And you want to parse the `src` attribute and require it automatically. 
In your js `myJS.js`,

```
var htmlA = require('../views/htmlA.html');
//render htmlA or bind the event, do whatever you want here.
```

Your webpack config should set to,

```
//webpack.config.js
loaders: [
    {
      //IMAGE LOADER
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
      loader:'file'
    },
    {
      // HTML LOADER
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'html-loader'
    }
]
```

This would package your `whatever.png` into your output folder. And it will be define as a **WEBPACK_MODULE** and require it asynchronously. **Base on the `publicPath` in your webpack.config**

[Check the example1 from my repo.](https://github.com/TylerYang/webpack-image-examples/tree/master/example1)

**2. Use the [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader) and [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader), then load the image synchronously**

The image will be encoded into base64 string, and insert into your module.(So it will be loaded synchronously.)
Simply update your `webpack.config.js` into this,

```
//webpack.config.js
loaders: [
    {
      //IMAGE LOADER
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
      loader:'url'
    },
    {
      // HTML LOADER
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'html-loader'
    }
]
```

[Check the example2 from my repo.](https://github.com/TylerYang/webpack-image-examples/tree/master/example2)

**3. Use only the [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader) and require the images manually**

Let's say you have `MyComponent`, and you want to require your image,

```
//myJS
var imgContent = require('./xxx.png');//require the image, with url-loader, you will get the base64 encoded string

//set src with pure js

//var img = document.createElement('img');
//img.setAttribute('src', imgContent); //set it to src
//document.body.appendChild(img);

//set src with React ES5
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <img src={imgContent} />
        );
    } 
});
```

With this your `webpack.config` will be set like this,

```
//webpack.config.js
loaders: [
    { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url?limit=8192' } // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
]
```

[Check the example3 from my repo.](https://github.com/TylerYang/webpack-image-examples/tree/master/example3)

P.S. You can use the [webpack-image-loader](https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader) to minify your image.

Hope this would help.

Comment: Thanks! I could finally get image with your No.3 way! Thanks again your readable repo. In my case I could get image asset with `const eyeCatch = require('../../Resource/popon.jpg');` with public path is `publicPath: '/dist/',`. I couldn't get when `publicPath: '/assets/',`. I'm the beginner, so I'll know the cause later;)

Comment: My pleasure to help. Oh, I forgot to update my `publicPath`. My bad, would update that later.  : )