# How do i load images in react without specifically importing

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have seen the usual ways of loading images in react.

1. Use the public folder and then set the src normally
2. Import the image and then set it

```
import myimage from "../../assets/images/img.png";
<img src={image}/>
```

3. Require the image inline

```
<img src={require(`../../assets/images/img.png}`)} />
```

I'm looking to see if there is a way like in angular when you set the src for an image and the importing is handled automatically? I'm assuming ill have to playaround with HTMl-loader and file loader

I found this while I was looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242974/9802012

Answer (score 0):

You can put your image in the **public** folder and then just do the usual html import `<img src="./img.png" />`